# Go package not exporting function with capital letter

Tags: go, import, package

I am trying to import a package in Golang, however I am unable to refrence a function declared within the package.

The following code is for the package i'm trying to import.

```
//image.go
pacakage image
import "pixel"

type Image struct {
    Matrix [][]pixel.Pixel
}

func New(width, height int) *Image{
     //Code
}
```

The following code is for the main file

```
//main.go
pacakage main
import (
    "image"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    img := image.New(10,4)
    fmt.Println(img)
}
```

When I run the main.go with go run main.go I get an error that says

```
undefined: image.New
```

I have ensured that my function is defined with an uppercase letter so i'm unsure why I'm able to call the New function. I am however able to declare a new image.Image variable.

Edit:

The problem was that I was developing outside the designated GOPATH/src. I was creating a file outside the GOPATH and resetting my GOPATH to my work file. This prevented me from properly importing and compiling my packages.

Comment: In which folder is `image.go`?

Comment: in the src folder I have a folder called image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native library [Go "image" package](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) does not have any New method.

You would need to prefix your own image package with the name of your project/path within `$GOPATH` in order to make Go chose your own package, and not the native one.

See "[Package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names)"

> A Go package has both a name and a path.
>
> The package name is specified in the package statement of its source files; client code uses it as the prefix for the package's exported names. Client code uses the package path when importing the package.
> By convention, the last element of the package path is the package name:

```
import (
    "context"                // package context
    "fmt"                    // package fmt
    "golang.org/x/time/rate" // package rate
    "os/exec"                // package exec
)
```

The OP adds:

> `image` is in the `src` folder: I have a folder called `image`.

See "[Organizing Go code](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code)":

> Sometimes people set `GOPATH` to the root of their source repository and put their packages in directories relative to the repository root, such as "`src/my/package`".
>
> On one hand, this keeps the import paths short ("`my/package`" instead of "`github.com/me/project/my/package`"), but on the other it breaks go get and forces users to re-set their `GOPATH` to use the package.
> Don't do this.

Comment: Would the proper way to import packages be hosting a repository and importing from the repository?

For example, creating a github repo for the project and calling the package from the github url

Comment: @leme without hosting the repo, simply having a *local* folder *structure* different from just "`image`" (like `GOPATH/src/myproject/image`) would allow your code to reference `myproject.image.New()`. You don't have to create a remote repo for that.